# Erro "O thread de chamada não pode acessar este objeto porque ele pertence a um thread diferente."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Tenho uma aplicação WPF que preciso manipular um textBox. Porém ele dá o seguinte erro ao rodar a parte do código que manipulo o textBox: System.InvalidOperationException: 'O thread de chamada não pode acessar este objeto porque ele pertence a um thread diferente.' O erro acontece na linha "txt_transcriber.Text = e.Result.Text".

```
namespace solucao_desktop
{
public partial class TranscriberWindow : Window
{
    public TranscriberWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void transcribrer()
    {
        txt_transcriber.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("16c50d2a281d4e9cb0834d4ee3a5d9", "brazilsouth");
        speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "pt-BR";
        
        using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
        using var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
        var stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

        recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>  //Enquanto estiver captando algum áudio
        {
            txt_transcriber.Text = e.Result.Text;
        };

        recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();

        Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão a interface do sistema seja WinForms ou Wpf roda em uma thread própria então acessar elementos visuais de uma outra thread iniciada por algo como

```
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {Metodo()});
```

Simplesmente não é possível de forma direta, para realizar uma operação de interface em uma outra thread é preciso dar invoke na ação usando o dispatcher responsável pela mesma, um exemplo de implementação disso seria guardar o dispatcher da thread de UI ao iniciar a mesma para ele ser utilizado dentro da sua thread futuramente, como o exemplo abaixo

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        Dispatcher dispatcher;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        }

        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
               Task.Delay(1000);
               dispatcher.Invoke(() => ChangeColors());
           });
        }

        private void ChangeColors()
        {
            btnTest.Background = Brushes.Red;
            this.Background = Brushes.Blue;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Julgo que seja assim:

txt_transcriber.Invoke((Action)(() => txt_transcriber.Text = e.Result.Text);